# error log trying to install express

Tags: npm

work with debian testing repositories pointing to testing. I installed node, and express npm following some tutorials and I made some mistakes by not paying attention.

1.- First I did the following as root:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manag ...

```
# echo sid main deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sid.list
# apt-get update
# apt-get install nodejs # Documentation is great.
# node-v v0.4.12
```

2.- You should then have done the following http://www.freshblurbs.com/install-node-js-and-express-js-nginx-debian-lenny:

```
$ cd
$ curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
$ which npm
```

but rather as a user I did not realize and what I did as root and it did not change the directory, ie do the following:

```
# Curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
# Which npm
/usr/bin/npm
```

and if I go to that directory permissions are for root, but not whether they should be user.

```
/usr/bin $ ls-la npm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Jan 7 20:09 npm -> .. /lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
```

3.- In making the last step:

```
$ npm express install
$ express /tmp/foo&&cd/tmp/foo
```

or this to install for global

```
$ npm install-g express
$ express /tmp/foo&&cd/tmp/foo
```

and did the first, but when attempting the second with

```
$ npm install-g express
```

I get these errors

```
$ npm install-g express
npm ERR! Could not create / usr / lib / node_modules / ___express.npm
npm ERR! Error installing express@2.5.4 Error: EACCES, Permission denied '/ usr / lib / node_modules / ___express.npm'
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, Permission denied '/ usr / lib / node_modules / ___express.npm'
npm ERR! Report this * Entire * log at:
npm ERR! <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR! <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Linux 3.0.0-1-amd64
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "express"
npm ERR! cwd /home/luis
npm ERR! node-v v0.4.12
npm ERR! npm-v 1.0.106
npm ERR! path/usr/lib/node_modules/___express.npm
npm ERR! EACCES code
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging Can be found in details:
npm ERR! /home/luis/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Total I have a major mess, as there are in that situation I am.

I tested with this as helloworld.js node

```
var sys = require ('sys');
sys.puts ('Hello World');
```

and making a

```
$ Node helloworld.js
Hello World
It works, but I want to install Express to develop.
```

Is it a problem to install it as root?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem like yours.

My solution is:

```
$ sudo npm install-g express      
instead of：      
$ npm install-g express
```

Enter my password. It shows:

> Usage: npm
>
> where  is one of:
>       adduser, apihelp, author, bin, bugs, c, cache, completion,
>       config, deprecate, docs, edit, explore, faq, find, get,
>       help, help-search, home, i, info, init, install, la, link,
>       list, ll, ln, login, ls, outdated, owner, pack, prefix,
>       prune, publish, r, rb, rebuild, remove, restart, rm, root,
>       run-script, s, se, search, set, show, star, start, stop,
>       submodule, tag, test, un, uninstall, unlink, unpublish,
>       unstar, up, update, version, view, whoami
>
> npm  -h     quick help on 
>   npm -l           display full usage info
>   npm faq          commonly asked questions
>   npm help   search for help on 
>   npm help npm     involved overview
>   Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
>       /Users/(your personal account name)/.npmrc
>   or on the command line via: npm  --key value
>   Config info can be viewed via: npm help config
>
> npm@1.1.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm

It works. Hope my solution can help you;-)

Comment: after running this command with sudo it says
sudo: npm: command not found

Answer (score 0):

You may try `sudo npm express install`, and then enter your password of your system account

Answer (score 0):

when you install with:

> npm install somemodule -g

it installs the *somemodule* in /usr/local/lib/node_modules (-g: globally/system-wide) To successfully install a module globally, you'll need write access to the destination directory. Hence the need for sudo npm ...

if instead you do:

> npm install somemodule

2 choices there:

1. somemodule gets installed in ~/.npm for the current user only (at least on Ubuntu)
2. if a package.json file exists in the current directory, somemodule gets installed in the ./node_modules directory.

Note(1): npm temporarily uses ~/tmp during the installation.  if this directory doesn't already exist, it gets created.  if using *sudo npm*, it will do so with 'root' ownership, which will later yield an install error unless npm is again run with sudo.  Fix: *chowm -R `whoami` ~/tmp*

Note(2): to use global modules, make sure that you have NODE_PATH defined in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem of installing express due to version compatibility, based on the following link : http://expressjs.com/migrating-4.html

i run the following commands :

1- npm uninstall -g express

2 npm install -g express-generator

3- express --version

the last command retunrs 4.9.0 as version